# What exactly is this BIO_new_ssl_connect doing in this example from documentation?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

Here is the [full *client* example](https://linux.die.net/man/3/bio_f_ssl):

```
BIO *sbio, *out;
int len;
char tmpbuf[1024];
SSL_CTX *ctx;
SSL *ssl;

ERR_load_crypto_strings();
ERR_load_SSL_strings();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

/* We would seed the PRNG here if the platform didn't
 * do it automatically
 */

ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

/* We'd normally set some stuff like the verify paths and
 * mode here because as things stand this will connect to
 * any server whose certificate is signed by any CA.
 */

sbio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);

BIO_get_ssl(sbio, &ssl);

if(!ssl) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Can't locate SSL pointer\n");
  /* whatever ... */
}

/* Don't want any retries */
SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

/* We might want to do other things with ssl here */

BIO_set_conn_hostname(sbio, "localhost:https");

out = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
if(BIO_do_connect(sbio) <= 0) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to server\n");
       ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
       /* whatever ... */
}

if(BIO_do_handshake(sbio) <= 0) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Error establishing SSL connection\n");
       ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
       /* whatever ... */
}

/* Could examine ssl here to get connection info */

BIO_puts(sbio, "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n");
for(;;) {
       len = BIO_read(sbio, tmpbuf, 1024);
       if(len <= 0) break;
       BIO_write(out, tmpbuf, len);
}
BIO_free_all(sbio);
BIO_free(out);
```

About this it says:

> This SSL/TLS client example, attempts to retrieve a page from an SSL/TLS web server. The I/O routines are identical to those of the unencrypted example in bio_s_connect(3).

I found that after first finding [this](https://gist.github.com/darrenjs/4645f115d10aa4b5cebf57483ec82eca) and [this](https://gist.github.com/MartinMReed/6395285) which seem somewhat related but differ in a few pieces.

---

So I have a few questions about this.

I see that we are doing `SSLv23_client_method`, so it's the "client" method (as opposed to server method). What goes on under the hood as a result of this? I ask because they say in the comments right after:

> We'd normally set some stuff like the verify paths and
>   mode here because as things stand this will connect to
>   any server whose certificate is signed by any CA.

What does this mean? I don't have too much practice with SSL certificates, but I have done it a few times. What should be happening here to make it "robust" or "complete"?

Then they say this:

> We might want to do other things with ssl here
>
> `BIO_set_conn_hostname(sbio, "localhost:https");`

What kinds of "things with ssl" should we be doing here? To make it robust and complete.

Then there is this:

```
if(BIO_do_handshake(sbio) <= 0) {
```

Is this part important? I see that missing for example [here](https://gist.github.com/MartinMReed/6395285).

Then right after that they comment:

> Could examine ssl here to get connection info

What does this mean? Are we *supposed* to be validating something here? I don't follow.

That's basically it. It seems that this example would allow you to create an SSL-backed HTTP POST request to an HTTPS server. That's all I want to do, just be able to make HTTPS POST requests (or PATCH or whatever) to HTTPS servers. What do I need to add to this to make sure it follows the best practices in terms of security? If it's *a lot to add*, then what are the key takeaways/highlights I should focus on?

Comment: [This](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-openssl/) seems partly helpful, the first thing I've seen in a few hours.

Comment: [Here](http://intronetworks.cs.luc.edu/current/html/auxiliary_files/tls/tlsclient.c) is another bit of helpfulness. And [this](http://h30266.www3.hpe.com/odl/axpos/opsys/vmsos84/BA554_90007/ch04s03.html).